Any free program or application that can reroute serial connection on any OS over the network?
Although I found a post that kind of does what I was thinking, I was hoping for something more cross-platform so that it will work with both Windows and Linux. Can a serial device be redirected over a network? If so, is there a program that can do this everywhere? Below are two different use cases I can see the flow of connections for devices:
(windows) COMx --> IP ADDR --> /dev/ttySx (linux)

OR
/dev/ttySx (linux) --> IP ADDR --> (windows) COMx

